# React native date picker component works weird in android

Tags: react-native, datepicker

Just replicated my issue here https://snack.expo.io/vER5Zz59S

When running it on android, the date changes to the next day upon clicking the button 'ok' multiple times even though the date in the picker is not changed. Please correct me if I did something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the [prop](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#timezoneoffsetinminutes-optional-ios-and-android-only) `timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}`. Which Allows changing of the timeZone of the date picker.

Comment: Cool, that was the issue. Can you explain how this timeZoneOffsetInMinutes prop works?